# Display change notification

Tags: c#, events, winapi

Is there any way to know that computer monitor was changed to another one? I need to reset display settings to default, if new one connected.

Answer (score 6):

```
SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged += new EventHandler(SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged);
```

You'll need to add a reference to `Microsoft.Win32;`